# Is there an equivalent to Java -Xmx for python?

Tags: java, python, shell

I am used to running `.command` scripts with terminal that use java, which allocates an amount of memory by the arguments `-Xmx` and `-Xms`.

I am now using a `.sh` script with python and can't seem to figure out what the equivalent is.

EDIT: Let me explain a little more. Is it possible to do that in the shell script or am I stuck decompiling Python scripts?

Comment: Is it possible to do that in the shell script or am I stuck decompiling Python scripts?

Comment: have a look at the shell-builtin [`ulimit`](http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html). and _decompiling_ python _scripts_???

Comment: OH lol whoops. I dunno what I was thinking there :P. I just couldn't be bothered to go through the 20 or so of them xD